# Blueimp Jquery-File-Upload submits null file in MVC Controller through IE 9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload to upload files to my site.

The file uploads fine in Firefox and Chrome, but when I try to upload it from IE 9
the file parameter in Controller action is null.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection collection)
{
     var model = newObject();
     TryUpdateModel(model);                   
     model.ID = saveDocObject(model);

     Guid fileid = saveUploadedFile(model.ID, file);

     return Json(new { name = file.FileName, fid = fileid.ToString() });
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<div id="upload_files">
      <div id = "filediv">
          <input type="file" name="file" class="green"/>
          <button>Upload</button>
         <div>Upload it</div>
      </div>
</div>
<table id="files" width="200px">
</table>
```

And finally my jquery:

```
$('#upload_files').fileUpload({
    url: '/Document/UploadFile',
    method: 'POST',
    uploadTable: $('#files'),
    downloadTable: $('#files')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in my view form. 
Now the file uploads fine, but after that the IE is trying to save the response.
So in the controller method I changed the `content-type` to `"text/plain"` and now
everything works ok.